# Spring MVC4 REST webservice getting error 406

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-4, http-status-code-406

I am stuck in this part of code where I am getting HTTP 406 error.

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.

I searched for two days, tried every possibilities and could not figure out the solution. The server I use is tomcat8.

This is my controller class:

```
@RestController
public class WebServiceController {


@RequestMapping(value="/testpage",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public TestObject test(){
    TestObject to = new TestObject();
    to.setAge("er");
    to.setName("sdfsdf");
    return to;
}
}
```

my TestObject:

```
public class TestObject {

private String name;
private String age;
public String getName() {
    return name;    }
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;   }
public String getAge() {
    return age; }
public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age; }
}
```

my dispatcher servelet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"           
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.kpos.webservice"/>

</beans>
```

here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.kpos.play.ws</groupId>
<artifactId>CFBService</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>CFBService Maven Webapp</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>CFBService</finalName>
</build>
```

> I read like if we use @RestController annotation, it will automatically convert object to JSON using jackson in classpath &  @RestController automatically take care of @ResponseBody.

Comment: Could you copy/paste here the logs of your application, after configuring DEBUG level for `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc`? I don't see anything wrong in your current configuration.

Comment: Note that you always should use version-less schemas in your dispatcher servlet configuration, i.e. replace `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd` by `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd`, especially since you're using version 4.1 here.

Comment: @BrianClozel No error logs.. All I can get is this below log line when the controller is initialized:

  INFO: Mapped "{[/testpage],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public com.kpos.webservice.objects.TestObject com.kpos.webservice.controller.WebServiceController.test()

Answer (score 1):

Try to get all Jackson Libraries as the following Blog :

http://www.breathejava.com/restful-web-service-tutorial-spring-xml/

The problem is linked to a missing Library of Jackson.

Comment: your example is using both Jackson 1.x and Jackson 2.x, which is wrong - Spring requires Jackson 2.1+ as of version 4.1. The OP has the right dependencies.

Comment: I got it working by adding '/' as servlet mapping in web.xml. I did added the above jars stil it was showing same error.